# Textfield value updated and saved but field resets back to default value when form loaded again and button clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, save, textfield

**My program:** 
Textfield will display a default value and when button is clicked, value decrements by 1. I am able to save the form and reload at a later date and textfield value will display last saved value. When I click button to decrement again, value should decrement by 1 from saved value and not default value.

**My problem:** 
When I save the program after decrementing value and reload form later, the textfield value returns back to default value when I click the button to decrement. On initial form load, the correct value is displayed, its when I click the button that the value resets back to default.

**Here's the core areas of my program:**

```
class Play
{
    public int Total = 5110;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fText.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox1;
}

private void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myPlay.Total--;
    ftext.Text = myPlay.Total.ToString();
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox1 = fText.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    lblSaveNote.Text = "Saved " + DateTime.Now; 
}
```

Comment: Why Properties.settings.default.textBox1?? I think that cause the problem.Could you try to remove that line?

Comment: that's to store the current value when I click save button. I think the problem is around the ftext.Text = myPlay.Total.ToString(), which is inside btnButton1_Click. Cant figure though :(

Comment: I suggest you to put a messegeBox in the Form1_Load method. If the messegebox doesn't show up , that's the problem with the load method. Maybe you need to use Form1_Shown method.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it by replacing btnButton1_Click code with:

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox1--;
        fText.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox1.ToString();
```